# Telegraf 1.16 + inputs.modbus plugin: timeout problem

Tags: influxdb, modbus, telegraf

I am reading with Telegraf 1.16 some Janitza devices through the `inputs.modbus` plugin.
Telegraf is started manually and not as a service to ease tests and debugging.

This is the configuration:
[image: system image]

Unit1 is a UMG604 that acts as a Gateway: it receives Modbus/TCP messages, and if they don't match its modbus address number, relays them to the following units. These are linked through a RS485 line. That means the communication is half-duplex and the line is quite busy because we are trying to read 350+ registers at any tick (25 registers per device).

These units are read without any problem using two loggers I wrote, one in C, the other in Python/pymodbus, so I can exclude any hardware issue.

Settings are straightforward, and here is a skeleton of Telegraf configuration file:

```
[agent]
  interval="5s"   # sample time
  round_interval=true  # sample at rounded intervals :00, :05, :10, etc
  metric_batch_size=1000  
  metric_buffer_limit=10000  


[[inputs.modbus]]
  name = "UMG604_Gateway_unit1"
  slave_id = 1
  timeout = "2s"
  busy_retries = 10
  busy_retries_wait = "200ms"
  controller = "tcp://192.168.2.100:502"

  holding_registers = [
    { measurement="Unit1", name="Strom-1", byte_order="ABCD", data_type="FLOAT32-IEEE", scale=1.0, address=[1325,1326]},
    # <another 24 non consecutive registers here>
  ]

[[inputs.modbus]]
  name = "UMG103_unit2"
  slave_id = 2
  timeout = "2s"
  busy_retries = 10
  busy_retries_wait = "200ms"
  controller = "tcp://192.168.2.100:502"

  holding_registers = [
    { measurement="Unit2", name="", byte_order="ABCD", data_type="FLOAT32-IEEE", scale=1.0, address=[1325,1326]},
    # <another 24 non consecutive registers here>
  ]

[[inputs.modbus]]
  name = "UMG103_unit3"
  slave_id = 3
  timeout = "2s"
  busy_retries = 10
  busy_retries_wait = "200ms"
  controller = "tcp://192.168.2.100:502"

  holding_registers = [
    { measurement="Unit3", name="", byte_order="ABCD", data_type="FLOAT32-IEEE", scale=1.0, address=[1325,1326]},
    # <another 24 non consecutive registers here>
  ]

[[inputs.modbus]]
  name = "UMG103_unit4"
  slave_id = 4
  timeout = "2s"
  busy_retries = 10
  busy_retries_wait = "200ms"
  controller = "tcp://192.168.2.100:502"

  holding_registers = [
    { measurement="Unit4", name="", byte_order="ABCD", data_type="FLOAT32-IEEE", scale=1.0, address=[1325,1326]},
    # <another 24 non consecutive registers here>
  ]

[[inputs.modbus]]
  name = "UMG103_unit5"
  slave_id = 5
  timeout = "2s"
  busy_retries = 10
  busy_retries_wait = "200ms"
  controller = "tcp://192.168.2.100:502"

  holding_registers = [
    { measurement="Unit5", name="", byte_order="ABCD", data_type="FLOAT32-IEEE", scale=1.0, address=[1325,1326]},
    # <another 24 non consecutive registers here>
  ]

[[inputs.modbus]]
  name = "UMG103_unit6"
  slave_id = 6
  timeout = "2s"
  busy_retries = 10
  busy_retries_wait = "200ms"
  controller = "tcp://192.168.2.100:502"

  holding_registers = [
    { measurement="Unit6", name="", byte_order="ABCD", data_type="FLOAT32-IEEE", scale=1.0, address=[1325,1326]},
    # <another 24 non consecutive registers here>
  ]

[[inputs.modbus]]
  name = "UMG103_unit7"
  slave_id = 7
  timeout = "2s"
  busy_retries = 10
  busy_retries_wait = "200ms"
  controller = "tcp://192.168.2.100:502"

  holding_registers = [
    { measurement="Unit7", name="", byte_order="ABCD", data_type="FLOAT32-IEEE", scale=1.0, address=[1325,1326]},
    # <another 24 non consecutive registers here>
  ]

[[inputs.modbus]]
  name = "UMG103_unit8"
  slave_id = 8
  timeout = "2s"
  busy_retries = 10
  busy_retries_wait = "200ms"
  controller = "tcp://192.168.2.100:502"

  holding_registers = [
    { measurement="Unit8", name="", byte_order="ABCD", data_type="FLOAT32-IEEE", scale=1.0, address=[1325,1326]},
    # <another 24 non consecutive registers here>
  ]

[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
    urls = ["http://localhost:8086"]
    token = "XXXXXXX"
    organization = "demo_org"
    bucket = "demo_bucket"
```

**The problem**

The first units in the config file are read *quite* regularly, but unit 5..8 manifest almost always a timeout:

`dial tcp 192.168.2.100:502: i/o timeout`
`read tcp 192.168.2.XX:XXXX->192.168.2.100:502: i/o timeout`

There are not so many parameters to tweak (`timeout`, `busy_retry` and `busy_retry_wait` has been increased), so I don't know if what I experience is a wrong setting or a problem in the modbus plugin.

**Question 1**. How is Telegraf reading the devices? Are the requests multithreaded, so they are ideally read at the same time?

If this is the case, the culprit could be the gateway **UMG604** unit 1: it **only accepts 4 connections**.

**Question 2**: Is there a possibility to delay the reading of some of the units 2..8? If it is, I can read the first ones, then after a delay the second block, and then a third. The lack of simultainety is not an issue in my system.

As a workaround I wrote a minimal `input.exec` that reads and print out a JSON that is fed to Telegraf, but if possible I would like to use a standard solution based only on the standard plugin.

**EDIT 1 ############################################**

Alas the devices are not accessible for experimentation: I can only ssh a remote server where Telegraf is installed.

I know from experience that there are no particular issues when reading them in different times, so after some comments I assume the problem is due to UMG604 accepting only 4 incoming connection at the same time.

Reading up to 3 devices (in any combination) never generates timeouts.

Any idea about how to activate a delayed reading of some of them? It could be a test that proves the point.

**EDIT 2 ############################################**

A quick recap: the error IS NOT generated by UMG604 limited number of connections.

All 8 connections open correctly, 4 soon, 4 in a later time.
The problem is the Modbus/RTU reading of UMG103 units: it looks like after the first successful readings they just stop returning data. As I told, tests cannot be done in loco.

There is an error but no return code for the error from `getFields` (`ok=false`), and this means `Gather` function in `modbus.go` plugin just exits without even retrying to read again:

```golang
if err != nil {
    mberr, ok := err.(*mb.ModbusError)
    if ok && mberr.ExceptionCode == mb.ExceptionCodeServerDeviceBusy && retry < m.Retries {
        ...
        time.Sleep(m.RetriesWaitTime.Duration)
        continue  # try again, we are inside a for loop
    }

    # ok is false, so we jump here!
    disconnect(m)
    m.isConnected = false
    return err
}
```

Alas forcing to retry on ANY error doesn't work.

After an error I also tried closing and reopeningthe connection before retrying, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the RS485 2-wire or 4-wire? Have you tried _only_ connecting to e.g. unit 8 and not units 1 to 7?

Comment: Can you monitor the TCP traffic with Wireshark? I suspect you're onto something with the unit only accepting 4 connections. Telegraf is written in Go, which makes it easy to do parallel / async operations.

Comment: Is it possible to connect the Telegraf box to the RS485 network directly? Or possibly by some other serial connection e.g. RS232 between the Telegraf box and the UMG604? I suspect the telegraf client would understand the timing better if it knew it was talking serial.

Comment: I added some extra info in the description.

Comment: @jason, 2-wire RS485, not 4-wire RS422.

Comment: (after Edit 2): weird. Do you know whether the non-consecutive registers are polled as a single poll (register addresses are within a range of 120 addresses), or individually, or in groups?

Comment: And do you know the serial settings?

Comment: I'm guessing the C and pymodbus programs you wrote where synchronous, not async?

Comment: In theory, the UMG604 should only do synchronous polling on the serial bus, so I don't think that's the problem. I'm wondering whether the Telegraf modbus plugin is choosing its poll groups badly, e.g. one poll per register. Can you run tcpdump or similar on the site telegraf server? Wireshark could then answer the question about polling.

Comment: @Jason, to answer your questions in order:
1) registers are polled in groups; I also reduced the reading to 3 consecutive registers for each device, but the problem persists, so it is not determined by the numbers of groups of their size;
 
2) the serial settings are checked and working well with my other loggers; no communication errors on the line; 

3) my loggers are synchronous: that's why I introduced a delay based on the slave unit number in `[inputs.modbus]` "isolating" every read by the plugin that behaves asynchronously; 

4) alas the system is remote and I cannot test it.

Comment: Modifying your interval will fix your problem most likely. I have the exact same problem. im asking for 110 registries each for 12 slaves. Increasing the interval to 4 mins fixed the problem. with the workarounds i was able to get this value down to 2.5 mins but thats it. Its telegrafs problem not your hardwares. It's just not capable of handling this amount of data i dont think